# Index of an equivalence relation on the set of permutations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, equivalence-relations

Let $S_{2n}$ be the set of permutations of the following set $\left\{x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_n\right\}$. I define the equivalence relation on $S_{2n}$ that identifies the substring $x_iy_i$ with the substring $y_ix_i$ for every $i$. So that for example if $n=2$ $$x_1y_1x_2y_2=y_1x_1x_2y_2=y_1x_1y_2x_2=x_1y_1y_2x_2.$$
What's the index of this relation? I tried to approach this problem recursively but it's kinda messy and I'm stuck.

Comment: What is meant by the "index" of a relation?

Comment: The number of equivalence classes.

Comment: It seems you intend each $a_i$ to be one of the $x_i$ and each $b_i$ to be one of the $y_i.$ [you did not say that...]

Comment: Thank you for the correction.

Comment: This seems different from your previous version where you used $a_i,b_i$ since in the previous version we can pair up strings which are at start not in the order with subscripts occuring on the $x_i,y_i$ all going 1122...etc. In other words previously I might put $a_1=x_2,  b_1=y_2, a_2=x_1,b_2=y_1.$ As opposed to your present specification in which we would not identify $x_2y_2x_1y_1$ with $y_2x_2y_1x_1.$

Comment: If you leave things as in your last edit it would be simple to see the size of any equivalence class is $2^n.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of equivalence classes is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \binom nk (2n-k)!.
$$

*Proof:* First, I will define a particular set of representatives for each equivalence class. Given any word $w$ in the equivalence class $[w]$, the representative of $[w]$ is the result of making all possible moves of the form $y_ix_i\Rightarrow x_iy_i$ in $w$, for each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. Each representative will be a permutation which contains none of the substrings of the form $y_ix_i$  for any $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. Therefore, to count the number of equivalence classes, you can count the number strings that avoid $y_ix_i$ for each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. This is done via the principle of inclusion exclusion, and it results exactly in the above expression.

In more detail, you start with all $(2n)!$ permutations, then for each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, you subtract the permutations which contain the substring $y_ix_i$. Then, for each $i,j\in \{1,\dots,n\}$ with $i<j$, you must subtract the permutations which contain both $y_ix_i$ and $y_jx_j$. This continues with the three-fold, four-fold, and so on up to $n$-fold intersections.

Answer (score 0):

**This is incorrect**

Your equivalence classes are elements of a quotient group, where the group $N$ you are quotienting by is the minimal normal subgroup generated by your relation. This means the index you are after is
$|G/N|=[G:N]$.
$G$ has two subgroups, $S_x$ and $S_y$, isomorphic to $S_n$. It is generated by these subgroups together with any one swapping element, e.g. $(x_1y_1)$.
Almost all (maybe all?) of the swapping terms get identified with $1$ in $G/N$: Your relation gives
$$(x_1y_1)(x_2y_1)=(x_2y_1)(x_1y_1)$$
$$\implies(x_1x_2y_1)=(x_2x_1y_1)=\sigma$$
But clearly $(x_1x_2y_1)$ and $(x_2x_1y_1)$ are inverses, so
$$\sigma=\sigma^{-1}\implies\sigma^2=1$$
But $\sigma$ is a permutation of 3 elements, so we have $\sigma^3=1$.
Therefore we get $\sigma=1$ in the quotient group. The same argument applies to any 3-cycles containing at least one $x$ and $y$ element. Any even permutation in G can be generated by these together with $S_x$ and $S_y$($S_{2n}$ is generated by its 3-cycles, and every 3-cycle either gets identified with $1$ in $G/N$ or is in $S_x$ or $S_y$.). So in the quotient, any even permutation can be generated by just $S_x$ and $S_y$. Assuming I haven't made a mistake.

Edit:

But there are also elements in $S_x$ and $S_y$ which are odd, which means that more than half of the elements of $S_{2n}$ are generated by $S_x$, $S_y$, and permutations which get quotiented out. But that means the entire group must be, as the subgroup they generate has an index less than $2$. Hence every element in $G/N$ can be generated by the image of $S_x$ and $S_y$. As $S_x$ and $S_y$ commute and generate the whole group, and there are no relations between them in $G/N$ other than that they commute,$G/N \cong S_x \times S_y$. So $|G/N| = |S_x| \times |S_y| = n!^2$

Comment: Im struggling to see why $(x_1x_2y_1)=(x_2x_1y_1)$ are the classes not closed under only switching an $x_i$ and $y_i$ when they are written next to each other? I might be misunderstanding something

Comment: @Carlyle It appears I misunderstood the question. I can't actually figure out what the question is actually asking though.

Comment: @ZoeAllen The rules are this; whenever $x_i$ and $y_i$ are adjacent in a permutation, you are allowed to switch their order to get an equivalent permutation. The question is, up to equivalences, how many distinct permutations are there? The OP gave examples of four permutations which are all equivalent to each other, because of these switching rules.